# Chain rule for general manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

So, I need an explanation why shall it be

$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}(f(\phi_X^t(m)) = d_m f \frac{d}{dt}\phi_X^t(m)|_{t=0}$

where $\phi_X^t$ is a flow, m is point in a given differentiable manifold M. I was thinking of some chain rule and read that there is some generalisation of chain rule to manifolds, but still can not see this. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is a chain rule for manifolds but this also follows immediately from the definition of the differential. If we set $\gamma(t) = \phi_X^t(m)$ then $\gamma$ is a curve satisfying $\gamma(0) = m$ and $\dot{\gamma}(t) = X(\gamma(t))$. Hence, by the definition of the differential,

$$ \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(\gamma(t)) = df|_{\gamma(0)}(\dot{\gamma}(0)) = df|_m(X_m).$$